# Scrapy crawl with next page. Proper rule syntax

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm trying to do recursive web scraping using scrapy. I would like to to go to 'https://www.doz.pl/apteka/k17_1-Przeciwbolowe' and by following next button get all products names and prices from this website.

I was able to create this spider (which works properly):

```
import scrapy

from DOZ2.items import prodItem
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule

class DmozSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "DOZ2"
    allowed_domains = ["doz.pl"]
    start_urls = ["https://www.doz.pl/apteka/k17_1-Przeciwbolowe"]

    def parse(self, response):

        for sel in response.xpath('//div[@class="details"]'):
            i=prodItem()
            i['price'] = sel.xpath('div[@class="price"]/span/text()').extract()[0]
            i['name'] = sel.xpath('h3/a/text()').extract()[0]
            i['link'] = sel.xpath('h3/a/@href').extract()[0]
            yield i

        if response.xpath('//li[@class="next"]/a/@href'):
            url= response.xpath('//li[@class="next"]/a/@href').extract()[0]
            url= ''.join(['https://www.doz.pl', url])  
            request = scrapy.Request(url=url)
            yield request
```

But to make code more professional according to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32624033/scrapy-crawl-with-next-page) I would like to do it by implementing 'rules'.I changed the code as in example but it doesn't work. It even don't get data from the main page.

```
# -*- coding: iso-8859-2 -*-

import scrapy

from DOZ2.items import prodItem
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule

class DmozSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "DOZ2b"
    allowed_domains = ["doz.pl"]
    start_urls = ["https://www.doz.pl/apteka/k17_1-Przeciwbolowe"]
    rules = (Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=(), restrict_xpaths=('//li[@class="next"]/a',)), callback="parse_page", follow= True),)

    def parse_page(self, response):

        for sel in response.xpath('//div[@class="details"]'):
            i=prodItem()
            i['price'] = sel.xpath('div[@class="price"]/span/text()').extract()[0]
            i['name'] = sel.xpath('h3/a/text()').extract()[0]
            i['link'] = sel.xpath('h3/a/@href').extract()[0]
            yield i
```

I would be grateful if someone could indicate what I'm doing wrong that my 2nd code doesn't work? I did all required changes: created rule, change name of parse function, ajusted restricted-path.

Thank you in advance for help.

Comment: when you create your spider class you should inherit from `scrapy.spiders.CrawlSpider` rather than `scrapy.Spider` if you want to use the rules

Comment: I missed that. It is working now. Thank you!

Comment: Cheers! I've posted the answer so the other could find it more easily, not everyone reads the comments unfortunately. On the side note checkout the documentation for other cool Spiders scrapy has and the crawlspider itself: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html?highlight=crawlspider#crawlspider

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are quite few `Spiders` in scrapy all of them just extend the `scrapy.Spider` and add in some features. To use [CrawlSpider](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html?highlight=crawlspider#crawlspider) you actually need to inherit from it when creating your spider class:

```
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider
class MyCrawlSpider(CrawlSpider):
     name = 'crawlspider1'
     rules = ... # define your rules here
```