# crawl spider doesn't proceed to next page

Tags: python, web-crawler, scrape

I'm scraping all products details on http://www.ulta.com/makeup-eyes-eyebrows?N=26yi. My rules are copied below. I only got data from the first page and it doesn't proceed to next page.

```
rules = (Rule(LinkExtractor(
            restrict_xpaths='//*[@id="canada"]/div[4]/div[2]/div[3]/div[3]/div[2]/ul/li[3]/a',), 
            callback = 'parse',
            follow =True),)
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Use the CrawlSpider as mentioned in the below question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32624033/scrapy-crawl-with-next-page

Comment: I think my code exactly follows the crawl spider in the link above. but not working

Answer (score 0):

Use the CrawlSpider, it will automatically crawl to other pages, otherwise with,
Spider , you need to manually pass the other links

```
 class Scrapy1Spider(CrawlSpider):
```

instead of

```
 class Scrapy1Spider(scrapy.Spider):
```

See: [Scrapy crawl with next page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32624033/scrapy-crawl-with-next-page)

Comment: I am using crawl spider instead of spider. and the restrict_xpaths is the xpath for the next button. but it's scraping only the first page.

Comment: Check if the other links are a part of allowed_domains variable. Why are you not adding allow() in LinkExtractor.

Comment: problem solved. an error of a product occurred when scraping the first page.