# Scrapy Link Extractor Rules

Tags: scrapy

I have a spider setup using link extractor rules.  The spider crawls and scrapes the items that I expect, although it will only follow the 'Next' pagination button to the 3rd page, where the spider then finishes without any errors, there are a total of 50 pages to crawl via the 'Next' pagination.  **Here is my code:**

```
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import Rule, CrawlSpider


class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'my_spider'
    start_urls = [some_base_url]

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow='//div[@data-test="productGridContainer"]//a[contains(@data-test, "product-title")]'), callback='parse_item'),
        Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths='//div[@data-test="productGridContainer"]//a[contains(@data-test, "next")]'), follow=True)
    )

    def parse_item(self, response):
        # inspect_response(response, self)

        ...items are being scraped

        return scraped_info
```

It feels like I may be missing a setting or something as the code functions as expected for the first 3 iterations.  My settings file does not override the DEPTH_LIMIT default of 0.  Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you.

**EDIT 1**
It appears it may not have anything to do with my code as if I start with a different product page I can get up to 8 pages scraped before the spider exits.  Not sure if its the site I am crawling or how to troubleshoot?

**EDIT 2**
Troubleshooting it some more it appears that my 'Next' link disappears from the web page.  When I start on the first page the pagination element is present to go to the next page.  When I view the response for the next page there are no products and no next link element so the spider thinks it it done.  I have tried enabling cookies to see if the site is requiring a cookie in order to paginate.  That doesnt have any affect.  Could it be a timing thing?

**EDIT 3**
I have adjusted the download delay and concurrent request values to see if that makes a difference.  I get the same results whether I pull the page of data in 1 second or 30 minutes.  I am assuming 30 minutes is slow enough as I can manually do it faster than that.

**EDIT 4**
Tried to enable cookies along with the cookie middleware in debug mode to see if that would make a difference.  The cookies are fetched and sent with the requests but I get the same behavior when trying to navigate pages.

Answer (score 1):

To check if the site denies too many requests in short time you can add the following code to your spider (e.g. before your `rules`statement) and play around with the value. See also the excellent [documentation](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#download-delay).

```
custom_settings = {
    'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 0.4
}
```

Comment: Thank you Frank, I have been messing with the download delay values as well as concurrent requests.  Even set at 60 secs, taking almost 30 minutes to pull a single page of data the spider stops.  I didn't know about the custom settings override, thats nice, better than messing in the settings.py all the time.

Comment: Sorry to hear that this does not help. Probably you did also try to set the `USER_AGENT` setting to some non default value already?

Comment: Yes, I have tried a lot of different values for USER_AGENT as well as ignoring or following the robots.txt file.

Comment: Without knowing the site I can only try to guess what's going on. You could try to use a regular Spider (not CrawlSpider) and create the requests explicit. Then add a lower priority to the next_page requests so that those are not submitted before any items of a former page. So your spider behaves like a normal user with a regular web browser (but faster). See another [so answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32624033/scrapy-crawl-with-next-page/32626667#32626667) for an example of manual requests.